# Why does my credit card validator get "int object is not subscriptable"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do my own credit card validator (Luhn algorithm). And here's my problem:

```
int object is not subscriptable
```

I tried to understand what it means but other people having this problem seemed to put a "str" to their code. Could someone help me and explain me why it is needed?

```
def main():
creditNums = int(input("Enter your credit card number mate: "))


reverseNums = creditNums[::-1]
oddNum = reverseNums[3:]
oddNums =  oddNum[::2]
for num in oddNums:
    nums_sum1 += num

evenNum = reverseNum[2:]
evenNums = evenNum[::2]
for i in evenNums:
    evenDouble.append(i*i)
if i in evenDouble > 9:
    i - 9
else:
    i
for num in evenDouble:
    nums_sum2 += num



sumNum = nums_sum2 + nums_sum1 
modNum = sumNum % 10

if m

odNum == 0:
        print("your card number is chill")
    else:
        print("your card is invalid bitch, your going to jail mamene")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is this `if m` ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that numbers don't support slicing (using `[]`).

That's why a solution is to use strings, because strings do support slicing.

Here is a quick example:

```
>>> i = 4356789
>>> i[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
>>> i = '4356789'
>>> i[3]
'6'
```

In your code, at the very top you convert the input to a number, and then try to do the slicing operations.

Only convert the input to a number when you want to do math on the input, otherwise leave it as a string.